# Watch only app binary rejected due to missing HealthKit info.plist keys

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect, watchos

I am having a confusing problem with my Apple Watch only app that uses HealthKit.  I keep receiving Binary Rejected upon uploading to App Store Connect due to missing NSHealthShareUsageDescription and NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription keys in the info.plist.  I have these keys in my info.plist and have verified that they are identical to my previous iOS apps that utilize Helathkit and have been successfully been uploaded.  Is this a problem with WatchOS only apps specifically?

[My info.plist keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrhzv.jpg)

Comment: Suggest checking if correct `info.plist` was used. Also check the main project's `info.plist`. Or are u using multiple targets(schema) with different info.plist?

Comment: I believe it is the correct one.  There are two info.plists.  The one shown above is the extension's Plist.  The other one is for the WatchKit App  If I place those keys into the other Plist (the watchkit app one) then I get an error before I can even uplaod to App Store Connect telling me that the keys are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on this site: [learningswift.brightdigit.com](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/independent-watch-app-healthkit-permissions/).  Apparently I needed to create a third Info.plist file in the project under the Xcode project file. [image]

Comment: This and adding the Info.plist to the main target helped fix my problem! Thanks @Jake. Unfortunately it is not very obvious, hopefully apple provides better support for the Watch only template in the future.